# Openoffice BASIC: Macros assigned to buttons are not working on other computers.

Tags: macros, openoffice.org, openoffice-calc, basic

So I have noticed that my codes in OpenOffice Calc (BASIC) are only working on my own computer. The macros are offcourse stored in the file and can be accessed through the Macro Organizer on any other computer (they even run through the Macro Organizer). Even then, they can only be assigned to a button on these other computers if I copy the code and paste it on Mymacros. I have already set the Macro Security Settings to Medium so it does not seem to be the problem.

The code is also not a problem. Even a simple macro such as:

```
Sub Main
Msgbox ("hello")
End Sub
```

assigned to a Button present the same behavior on other computers.

Answer (score 0):

I created another Library apart from the standard one and saved the macro there. This allowed the macros to run in every computer.